# Why do the cells have the same width as the label?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a simple `UICollectionViewController` in my Storyboard, with custom cells with a single `UILabel` inside of them.

[image]

When I run the project with mock data the cells have the same width as the labels even though I made the controller conform to `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` and added the following code:

```swift
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: self.collectionView.frame.width / 2.5, height: 100)
    }
```

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: is this function executing ? add breakpoint and check ... you added delegate ?

Comment: have you added `collectionView.delegate = self`

Comment: @jawadAli The answer to both questions is yes.

Comment: `let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal 

self.collectionView?.setCollectionViewLayout(layout, animated: true)` try to add this code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the storyboard, select the collection view and switch to the Size inspector. You will see something like this:

[image]

Change Automatic to None.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Storyboards, try giving Label inside a view and give leading as well as trailing constraints accordingly.
hope it solves your problem.